# Gitlab 6.2 asking for username and password authentication when pushing to origin

Tags: git, http, gitlab

I'm running GitLab 6.2 on a Linux Debian box and it looks like I can't push to the remote repository from the command line.

Every time I do a

`git push -u origin master`

it asks for the username and password (I've added the origin as an HTTP remote)

Comment: Does it accept your GitLab username and password?

Comment: @AshWilson Yes, it does accept the username/password combo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check that your remotes aren't set to use http/https:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://somedomain.com/username/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://somedomain.com/username/repo.git (push)
```

If it looks like the above, try switching to using ssh like so:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin git@somedomain.com:username/repo.git
```

Comment: As you noticed I was trying to use SSH over HTTP. Switching the remote origin to SSH did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your key to your server.
If you are using linux or mac you can follow this [tutorial](http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~cs363/2013-spring/gitlab-intro.html)

Comment: I've already done that. I'm using the same public key that I'm using for other systems like GitHub, another box running standard git behind Apache, etc..

Comment: Ok. Did you add that key to gitlab?

Comment: Indeed. If I cat the content of /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys I can see my public key there.

Comment: That's interesting. Go to Source Tree settings, take a look at the keys it is using and check if the key it is using is different than yours. Maybe, Maybe! you are using a different user?

Comment: You're right, it had the user credentials saved. I removed them and now it's asking for my username and password, so even SourceTree isn't using the SSH key. BTW I double checked and it's the same user.

Comment: Oh snap! I didn't tell you to delete it from source tree, what I told you to do is to see if that key was different than yours. At this point I would try what @JBarberU is saying.

Comment: I didn't have a key stored in SourceTree. I had the username/password combo stored, which is what I deleted to check if it worked by using the account's ssh key :)